# If possible how do you use a Tesla V100 on Windows Server 2016 for rendering in DX or OpenGL/gaming?

Tags: drivers, nvidia-graphics-card, windows-server-2016, rendering, nvidia-settings

Our team has a Windows Server 2016 running multiple Tesla V100 (16GB). The GPUs are primarily used for machine learning tasks but now we need to do some "gaming" (it's actually a simulator but it "plays" like a game) on one. We don't have direct access to the server and we connect to it via RDP+LDAP. Along with the multiple Teslas the system has a weak and old Quadro that is automatically used for rendering the remote session of all users.

Once the simulator starts it crashes right after the splash screen with an error:

> DX11 error: Error creating pixel shader: 80070057

While it may be just poorly written application (not excluding it due to the whole fuss I had to go through to download and install it) I would like to exclude the possibility that it is due to the application using the "wrong" (weak Quadro) GPU.

I went to the Nvidia Setting panel (or however it's called) and decided to create a new profile for that application in particular. I noticed two things:

- For CUDA I get two groups of options - global (currently all GPUs - Teslas and Quadro - selected) and custom (where I can select specific GPUs for this particular profile). All GPUs are visible here
- For OpenGL Rendering GPU I have three options - global, automatic and Quadro. No Tesla is visible here.

I looked and I couldn't see any DirectX setting in the whole profile configuration, which is weird in itself but imho not the main issue. I tried finding information on the rendering capabilities of the Tesla but officially (Nvidia Datasheet) I couldn't (it's all marketing materials on high performance computing, data centers and so on). Other GPU benchmarking online platforms do provide such information (supports DX12 and OpenGL 4.6).

Is this a driver issue perhaps? Some drivers do disable features. Or maybe I am looking at the wrong configuration parameters.

PS: The closest I could get to any information on OpenGL (not even DX) and the V100 is at https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/can-i-use-opengl-in-windows-10-with-tesla-v100-gpu/67002/4.

Comment: Have you verified these cards even have support for feature level 11_0?  Looking at dxdiag won't provide an accurate measure of the card's DX and OpenGL capability.  Thankfully, Nvidia, provides that information on their specifications for their cards.

Comment: @Ramhound I checked the datasheet but I couldn't find any information. However 90% of it is about cost, HPC and data centers, which clearly indicated where the focus is. In addition "NVIDIA V100 Tensor Core is the most advanced data center GPU ever built to accelerate AI, high performance computing (HPC), data science and **GRAPHICS**" is written on the product's website. No I now once can use CUDA to speed up rendering but in the end you do need a standard pipeline (D3D or OpenGL) for a non-embedded GPU to output stuff. TechPowerUp's description of the product also clearly states DX12.